# error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin iOS application that can run fine on my device when I start the application on "Debug" configuration. Now I created a new configuration called "Staging" and duplicated the `info.plist` and `entitlements.plist` as `info-Staging.plist` and `entitlements-Staging.plist` and want to use those while debugging in the "Staging" configuration. The only difference between them is a different identifier (com.blah.blah). I edited the `.csproj` as so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="packages.config" />

  <None Include="Entitlements.plist" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Staging'" />

  <None Include="Info.plist" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Staging'" />

  <None Include="Info-Staging.plist" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Staging'">
    <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName>
  </None>

  <None Include="Entitlements-Staging.plist" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Staging'">
    <LogicalName>Entitlements.plist</LogicalName>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Staging|AnyCPU' ">
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Staging</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants></DefineConstants>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
  <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements-Staging.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
  <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>true</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
  <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
  <MtouchHttpClientHandler>HttpClientHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
  <AssemblyName>MyApp.iOS</AssemblyName>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD;</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
  <DeviceSpecificBuild>true</DeviceSpecificBuild>
  <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
  <MtouchFastDev>true</MtouchFastDev>
  <MtouchFloat32>true</MtouchFloat32>
  <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
  <MtouchTlsProvider>Default</MtouchTlsProvider>
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But when I try to build the app on my device, I get this message:

`error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.2.1 (14D27) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files.`

Comment: try to delete the bin and obj  folder  and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that

Comment: What is the reason you defined the condition as `Staging|AnyCPU` instead of `Staging|iPhone`?

Comment: No reason. I just want to use a different identifier. That's the only difference I need.

Comment: So, can you change it to `Staging|iPhone` and check if it helps?

Comment: I changed it to `Staging|iPhone` and now it doesn't let me choose my device as the target when building...thus there is a red "X" next to my iOS project that says `invalid configuration mapping` when I move my mouse over it

Comment: *A simple test case to reproduce the issue would be very helpful here (:*

Also may I point to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt1108-could-not-find-developer-tools-for-this-xx-yy-device.  

Can you check you have the `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg` for the Xcode that you chose in your IDE options?

Answer (score 0):

This Problem is very simple Actually Just check if the Installed Xcode version in your MAC machine and the Xamarin version that you have right now in your System match. For that you need to check in Visual studio as Tools/Options/Xamarin

Comment: That can't be it because it works when I use the "Debug" configuration.

Comment: Are you sure the custom config you have created is proper ? @Darius

Comment: Well there must be something wrong with it since it works on other configurations...when I build, it actually builds successfully, but hangs when the status shows `Waiting for the debugger to connect to iPhone...`, and in the application output I see `error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.2.1 (14D27) device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files.`

Comment: See i have been working on xamarin ios for a while now and what i understand from the error message is that you are missing some support files that are needed to build using your configuration but i'm not sure which i guess you should check for development support files for your device version i.e. 10.2.1
Search for something like "**Development support files for ios 10.2.1**"

Comment: Even though I am getting the same message, i continued debugging and it is working